# Add CROSS JOIN to Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I like to add CROSS JOIN to my RoR application. When using Arel one can add joins like this:

`cars.joins(Car.arel_table.join(Part.arel_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(Car.arel_table[:id].eq(Part.arel_table[:car_id]))`

In my case I need a CROSS JOIN but it is not available in Arel. How can I add a CROSS JOIN to Arel?

I found the OuterJoin class and I added a new file with the following code:

`module Arel
  module Nodes
    class CrossJoin < Arel::Nodes::Join
    end
  end
end`

But that seems like it is not enough to make it work. I get a TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::CrossJoin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself after browsing trough the Arel sources. I needed to add a Visitor method to Arel to make it work, I copied the visit_Arel_Nodes_InnerJoin method and renamed it.

```
module Arel
 module Nodes
   class CrossJoin < Arel::Nodes::Join
   end
 end
 module Visitors
   class ToSql
     def visit_Arel_Nodes_CrossJoin o, collector
       collector << "CROSS JOIN "
       collector = visit o.left, collector
       if o.right
         collector << SPACE
         visit(o.right, collector)
       else
         collector
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

end